# User control or custom control for this design?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

[image]

If I want to create a button control like that, is it supposed to be a User Control or a Custom Control? I  am not sure maybe something else? Ideally I want to be able style/animate the main button and the inner button separately; also obviously Ill need to process their events separately. These buttons will be created at run-time and Ill need to set the icons dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a user control. You can still create your basic styling in xaml and use code for the dynamic stuff.

You'd basically have something like this:

```
    <Button>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Your button text</TextBlock>
            <Image Source="" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

Comment: I haven't thought that I should make the inner button an Image... Thanks! I'll give it a try and see how this works.